# Magento 2: How to get add to cart url in custom templete file and add product to cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart

i am not able to get add to cart url in my custom template files , here is my code

```
$postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
$postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($product), ['product' => $product->getEntityId()]);
```

**O/p:->**

```
string(110) "{"action":null,"data":{"product":"392","uenc":"aHR0cDovLzQ1LjMzLjEyMi42Ni9ib25hZ2UvaW5kZXgucGhwL3Rlc3QtMi8,"}}"
```

**My add to cart form code is :**

```
<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" validate="validate">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php echo $postParams['data'][\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
       <div class="view-detail">
      <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>" class="action tocart primary">
      <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
     </button> </div>
    </form>
```

while i submit form only page is load because i am getting null in post action. 
Please help me to complete my add to cart code in my custom template files

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this, it work for me.

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
$addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product);
?>

<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post"> 
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <div class="btn">
        <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">
            <span>Add to Cart</span>
        </button>
    </div>   
 </form>
```

Comment: That work really for simple product that hasn't got a configurable
the mini-cart display nicely everything product details but when adding a variation in the mini-cart does not display the details but price everything else is missing I've also set `'selected_configurable_option'` and `super_attribute` but still the same do you know of how to fix this thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Adding upon [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/180224/67479), if you wanted to do this through a non-object manager way you can do it with the following.

Add the list block to your constructor

```
/**
 * ...
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $listBlock
 */
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $listBlock
)
{
    ...
    $this->listBlock = $listBlock;
    ...
}
```

Then in whatever method you want add in the following.

```
public function execute()
{
    return $this->listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product);
}
```